# Spring boot throws "com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.operations.cloudsdk.process.ProcessHandlerException"

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to deploy my spring boot web application to google cloud. I've followed the steps specified in the below document -

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-app-engine-springboot#1.

But every time I deploy my application to the google cloud I get **com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.operations.cloudsdk.process.ProcessHandlerException: com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.AppEngineException: Non zero exit: 1**

But it doesn't give any specific error message even in debug mode.

I tried to troubleshoot it taking reference from other questions but none worked for me.

I'll appreciate any help.

Run Logs -

```
[INFO] GCLOUD: -XX:InitialHeapSize=514850816 -XX:MaxHeapSize=514850816 -XX:+ParallelRefProcEnabled -XX:+PrintCommandLineFlags -XX:+UseCompressedClassPointers -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+UseG1GC 
[INFO] GCLOUD: I1030 15:32:39.799994    58 jvmti_globals.cc:331] Build time: Sep 14 2020 08:10:39
[INFO] GCLOUD: I1030 15:32:39.803900    58 jvmti_agent.cc:159] Java debuglet initialization started
[INFO] GCLOUD: I1030 15:32:39.804445    58 jvmti_agent.cc:193] Java debuglet initialization completed
[INFO] GCLOUD: I1030 15:32:39.863389    58 jvmti_agent.cc:204] Java VM started
[INFO] GCLOUD: I1030 15:32:39.890007    58 jvmti_agent.cc:214] JvmtiAgent::JvmtiOnVMInit initialization time: 26614 microseconds
[INFO] GCLOUD: I1030 15:32:39.890761    69 jvmti_agent_thread.cc:95] Agent thread started: CloudDebugger_main_worker_thread
[INFO] GCLOUD: I1030 15:32:39.891149    69 jvm_internals.cc:370] Loading internals from /opt/cdbg/cdbg_java_agent_internals.jar
[INFO] GCLOUD: openjdk version "1.8.0_275"
[INFO] GCLOUD: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_275-8u275-b01-1~deb9u1-b01)
[INFO] GCLOUD: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.275-b01, mixed mode)
[INFO] GCLOUD: 
[INFO] GCLOUD: I1030 15:32:40.435465    69 jvmti_agent.cc:365] Initializing Cloud Debugger Java agent version: 2.26
[INFO] GCLOUD: I1030 15:32:40.438211    69 jni_logger.cc:31] Initializing ClassPathLookup, default classpath: true, extra classpath: [/var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/WEB-INF/classes, /var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/WEB-INF/lib]
[INFO] GCLOUD: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log: Logging initialized @763ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[INFO] GCLOUD: I1030 15:32:41.660717    69 jni_logger.cc:31] Total size of indexed resources database: 413931 bytes
[INFO] GCLOUD: I1030 15:32:41.926803    69 jvm_internals.cc:131] ClassPathLookup constructor time: 1489881 microseconds
[INFO] GCLOUD: I1030 15:32:41.932482    69 yaml_data_visibility_config_reader.cc:35] debugger-blacklist.yaml was not found.  Using default settings.
[INFO] GCLOUD: org.eclipse.jetty.setuid.SetUIDListener: Setting umask=02
[INFO] GCLOUD: org.eclipse.jetty.setuid.SetUIDListener: Opened ServerConnector@4e9ba398{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:8080}
[INFO] GCLOUD: org.eclipse.jetty.setuid.SetUIDListener: Setting GID=999
[INFO] GCLOUD: org.eclipse.jetty.setuid.SetUIDListener: Setting UID=999
[INFO] GCLOUD: org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server: jetty-9.4.35.v20201120; built: 2020-11-20T21:17:03.964Z; git: bdc54f03a5e0a7e280fab27f55c3c75ee8da89fb; jvm 1.8.0_275-8u275-b01-1~deb9u1-b01
[INFO] GCLOUD: org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider: Deployment monitor [file:///var/lib/jetty/webapps/] at interval 0
[INFO] GCLOUD: I1030 15:32:44.060986    69 jni_logger.cc:31] Debuggee gcp:946572402541:6b9924bd764d618d, agentId 61787602-0000-20a6-9801-240588747bcc, registered: {"debuggee":{"id":"gcp:946572402541:6b9924bd764d618d","project":"946572402541","uniquifier":"DA39A3EE5E6B4B0D3255BFEF95601890AFD80709","description":"my-project-329416-1-439050277135501998","agentVersion":"google.com/java-gcp/@2","labels":{"version":"1","minorversion":"439050277135501998"}},"agentId":"61787602-0000-20a6-9801-240588747bcc"}, agent version: 2.26
[INFO] GCLOUD: I1030 15:32:44.061256    69 jvmti_agent.cc:436] Attaching Java debuglet
[INFO] GCLOUD: I1030 15:32:44.065299    69 rate_limit.cc:139] CPU count: 1
[INFO] GCLOUD: I1030 15:32:44.065712    69 rate_limit.cc:147] Adjusted CPU count: 1
[INFO] GCLOUD: I1030 15:32:44.065822    69 debugger.cc:99] Initializing Java debuglet
[INFO] GCLOUD: I1030 15:32:44.090178    69 debugger.cc:108] Debugger::Initialize initialization time: 24 ms
[INFO] GCLOUD: 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  17:12 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-10-31T16:07:59+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-maven-plugin:2.4.1:deploy (default-cli) on project mygoogleapp: App Engine application deployment failed: com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.operations.cloudsdk.process.ProcessHandlerException: com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.AppEngineException: Non zero exit: 1 -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-maven-plugin:2.4.1:deploy (default-cli) on project mygoogleapp: App Engine application deployment failed
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: App Engine application deployment failed
    at com.google.cloud.tools.maven.deploy.AppDeployer.deploy(AppDeployer.java:59)
    at com.google.cloud.tools.maven.deploy.DeployMojo.execute(DeployMojo.java:35)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.AppEngineException: com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.operations.cloudsdk.process.ProcessHandlerException: com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.AppEngineException: Non zero exit: 1
    at com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.operations.Deployment.deploy(Deployment.java:98)
    at com.google.cloud.tools.maven.deploy.AppDeployer.deploy(AppDeployer.java:57)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.operations.cloudsdk.process.ProcessHandlerException: com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.AppEngineException: Non zero exit: 1
    at com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.operations.cloudsdk.process.LegacyProcessHandler.handleProcess(LegacyProcessHandler.java:87)
    at com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.operations.GcloudRunner.run(GcloudRunner.java:117)
    at com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.operations.Deployment.deploy(Deployment.java:96)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.AppEngineException: Non zero exit: 1
    at com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.operations.cloudsdk.process.NonZeroExceptionExitListener.onExit(NonZeroExceptionExitListener.java:28)
    at com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.operations.cloudsdk.process.LegacyProcessHandler.syncRun(LegacyProcessHandler.java:144)
    at com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.operations.cloudsdk.process.LegacyProcessHandler.handleProcess(LegacyProcessHandler.java:83)
    ... 26 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Below is my pom.xml file -

````
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.6</version>
            <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
        </parent>
        <groupId>com.props</groupId>
        <artifactId>arti</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <packaging>war</packaging>
        <name>MyGoogleApp</name>
        <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
        <properties>
            <java.version>1.8</java.version>
            <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
            <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
             <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
             <appengine.maven.plugin>1.3.2</appengine.maven.plugin>
        </properties>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
              <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
              <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>     
                <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>     
                <artifactId>gson</artifactId>          
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                   </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
             <dependency>
               <groupId>jstl</groupId>
               <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
               <version>1.2</version>
            </dependency> 
            <dependency>
                <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
                <version>1.4</version>
            </dependency>
            
             <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            </dependency>  
        </dependencies>
    
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
                    <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                    <version>1</version>
                        <deploy.projectId>my-project-329416</deploy.projectId>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    
    </project> ```
````

Comment: Please provide more information. What plugin causes the issue? Does the issue appear on the application startup? What else is in the application log?

Comment: Hi @EvgenyBovykin - I'm not sure about the culprit plugin. But I'm sharing the logs.